# How to add an on click event to my Line chart using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, onclick, linechart, chart.js

I am trying to add an on click event to my Line chart using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org). I already have my tool tips enabled to show the information from my line charts, but I would also like to add an on click method that will let me know where the user clicked on the x axis. For now I would just like an alert to pop up, giving me the value on the x axis where the user clicked.

RESEARCH:

I looked through the [documentation of Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-prototype-methods) and I came across this method: .getPointsAtEvent(event)

> Calling getPointsAtEvent(event) on your Chart instance passing an
>   argument of an event, or jQuery event, will return the point elements
>   that are at that the same position of that event.

```
canvas.onclick = function(evt){
    var activePoints = myLineChart.getPointsAtEvent(evt);
    // => activePoints is an array of points on the canvas that are at the same position as the click event. };
```

I just can't figure out how to use or where to place the function in my code. If anyone could help me figure out where I can add this to my code, it would be greatly appreciated!

MY CODE: (in javascript)

```
  //NOTE: the div 'roomForChart' has been already declared as <div id="roomForChart"></div>


 //creating html code inside of javascript to display the canvas used for the graph
 htmlForGraph = "<canvas id='myChart' width ='500' height='400'>";
 document.getElementById('roomForChart').innerHTML += htmlForGraph;

 //NOW TO CREATE DATA

   //the data for my line chart
    var data = {
         labels: ["Aug 1", "Aug 2", "Aug 3","Aug 4","Aug 5"], //the x axis
          datasets: [
            {   //my red line
                label: "Usage Plan",
                fillColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.2)", //adds the color below the line
                strokeColor: "rgba(224,0,0,1)",//creates the line
                pointColor: "rgba(244,0,0,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: [1024, 1024, 1024, 1024, 1024]
           },

       {    //my green line
            label: "Overall Usage",
            fillColor: "rgba(48,197,83,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(48,197,83,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(48,197,83,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(48,197,83,1)",
            data: [15, 25, 45, 45, 1500]
       },
        {  //my blue line
            label: "Daily Usage",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [15, 10, 20, 0, 5]
       }

     ] //ending the datasets
     }; //ending data


    //creating a variable for my chart
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");




//code to create a maximum y value on the chart
var maxUsage = 1024;
var maxSteps = 5;
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
    pointDot: false,
    scaleOverride: true,
    scaleSteps: maxSteps,
    scaleStepWidth: Math.ceil(maxUsage / maxSteps),
    scaleStartValue: 0

});

 //what I have tried but it doesn't show an alert message
ctx.onclick = function(evt){
    var activePoints = myLineChart.getPointsAtEvent(evt);
    // => activePoints is an array of points on the canvas that are at the same position as the click event.
   alert("See me?");
};
```

To those of you who have a hard time visualizing the chart here you go:

[image]

Hopefully I have provided enough information to get some help. Please let me know if I need to explain myself. Thank you in advance!!! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this line

```
document.getElementById('roomForChart').innerHTML += htmlForGraph;
```

to this

```
holder = document.getElementById('roomForChart');
holder.innerHTML += htmlForGraph;
```

and further you'll have your snippet, modified a bit

```
holder.onclick = function(evt){
    var activePoints = myLineChart.getPointsAtEvent(evt);
    // => activePoints is an array of points on the canvas that are at the same position as the click event.
   alert("See me?");
};
```

Add `console.log(activePoints);` within onclick handler to see the content of the `activePoints` variable. As I can see, there are three objects. For instance these are values for `activePoints[0]`

```
datasetLabel: "Usage Plan"
fillColor: "rgba(244,0,0,1)"
highlightFill: "#fff"
highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)"
label: "Aug 4"
strokeColor: "#fff"
value: 1024
x: 371
y: 12.356097560975627
```

And they may be accessed as following

```
activePoints[0].label
activePoints[0].x
activePoints[0].y
activePoints[0].value
```

It will be good to check if the property is `undefined` first, since there are no data behind every click event.

Comment: You rock! I knew I was close! Thank you for suggesting I use a holder. I never even thought of that!

Comment: Quick question! When I write alert(activePoints); An alert pops up with no information inside of it (I am guessing it is empty or null). How do I get/pull out that information?

Comment: @MadsterMaddness I just was reading that part; I'll drop you a note in a couple of minutes; just to figure out the format of output.

Comment: @MadsterMaddness The point is that there are no data for every pixel on the chart and that's why I was getting `undefined` error on a certain click event. So, just check if the property is `undefined` before you alert or show it ;) And check the last update.

Comment: I added a console log to activePoints[0]. I kept getting [Information] as a result until by some miracle when I clicked on the graph just right I got: [Information] (JavaScript.KKJSObject) { value : 1024d, label : "Aug 5", datasetLabel : "Usage Plan", strokeColor : "#fff", fillColor : "rgba(244,0,0,1)", ... } Why can't the chart round the label to the nearest value like the tool tip?

Comment: @MadsterMaddness Well, as you may know, we see a curve as a result of [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) of a few given data. So I'm not sure if chart calculates data for every point. I was working on a similar problem using [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) a few weeks ago and couldn't get to have a (let's say) rounded value on every click. I'll let you know if I menage to find a workaround.

Comment: Thank you so much for your insight on this. Good luck on your progress and please let me know if you get any closer. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

if youre using the new ChartJs version use this:

```
canvas.onclick = function(evt){
   var activePoints = myLineChart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
};
```

Comment: thanks bro, u saved my time ^_^ ! It perfectly works for new charjs version.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved my problem in version 2.1.6.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't get the `onclick` method to work.

But I finally managed to run it using the `click` method:

```
$("#canvas_id").click(function(e) {
   var activeBars = myBarChart.getBarsAtEvent(e); 
   console.log(activeBars[0]);
});
```

Note: this example if for the Bar chart - other charts have slightly different methods to retrieve the points (see the documentation).

Comment: I tried to use this approach but it didnt work for me and I am note sure why. The click event is attached I also debuged the function getBarsAtEvent but the retrieved bar is not the one I just clicked or sometimes just doesnt retrieve any data. The getPointsAtEvent is the method which you can pass in a click event, and it will a return an array of points at the location of that event but in my case sometimes retrieves an empty array.

Answer (score 5):

The answers provided to date are close to the correct solution(s), but are incomplete. You need to use the getElementsAtEvent() to get the correct elements, but this gives you a collection of elements that are at the clicked x-index. In the even that you are using more than one dataset, this could be several values, one from each data set.

To figure out the correct data set to pull from, call the getDatasetAtEvent() method. This will return a list of the elements that contains the clicked dataset element. Pick the dataset Id from any of them, they are all the same Id.

Put the two together and you have the call you need to figure out the data contained in the clicked element. Passing in more than just and x and y value when you init your data set will let you do all sorts of neat tricks with this event. (For example, trigger a popup with more detailed info about the event)

There might be a more succinct way of getting this data, but I didn't find it mucking around the chart docs and tickets. Perhaps they will add it in a future release.

```
// chart_name is whatever your chart object is named. here I am using a
// jquery selector to attach the click event.
$('#' + chart_name).click(function (e)
{
    var activePoints = myChart.getElementsAtEvent(event);
    var activeDataSet = myChart.getDatasetAtEvent(event);

    if (activePoints.length > 0)
    {
         var clickedDatasetIndex = activeDataSet[0]._datasetIndex;
         var clickedElementIndex = activePoints[0]._index;
         var value = myChart.data.datasets[clickedDatasetIndex].data[clickedElementIndex];
    }
    // todo: add code to do something with value.
});
```

Comment: You are a hero!

Answer (score 2):

**V3**

You can also use the build in `onClick` option which gets the following paramters: `(event, activeElements, chartInstance)`

So you can just read the array you get as second element to see which elements have been active. By default this array contains only 1 item but if you change your interaction modes multiple items could be in here.

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        backgroundColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    onClick: (evt, activeElements, chart) => {
      console.log(`DatasetIndex: ${activeElements[0].datasetIndex} DataIndex: ${activeElements[0].index}`)
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

In v3 the `getElementsAtEvent` has been removed and now you have to use: `chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(event, 'index', { intersect: true }, false)`

If you want to use `getDatasetAtEvent` you now have to use: `chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(e, 'dataset', { intersect: true }, false)`

Answer (score 0):

In current version(3.9.1) i could not find `.getPointsAtEvent(event)` no more.
As a workaround that worked for me I found in [Chart.js GitHub](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1283#issuecomment-379471050)
code sample

```
 var selectedPoint;
        ....
        options: {
            plugins: {
                tooltip: {
                    callbacks: {
                        afterBody: function(context) {
                           if(context && context[0])
                            selectedPoint = context[0];
                            return [''];
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            .....
            onClick: (e) => {
                console.log(selectedPoint);
            }
        }
```

Basicaly on tooltip generation you save data to variable `selectedPoint` and in `onClick` event you start using it.